# Apache mod_rewrite: path replaced with query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, qsa

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9_-]*)\.([a-z]+)$ index.php?id=$2&type=$3&size=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that when I go to the URL `/0/azerty.ext` in a browser the URL is displayed as `/index.php?id=azerty&type=ext&size=0`. What I want is the redirection to be performed, with `/0/azerty.ext` as the visible URL.

I tried to remove the `R=301` flag, but in that case the redirection is not performed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution (adding slash at the beginning of the redirected URL), not sure why though...

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9_-]*)\.([a-z]+)$ /index.php?id=$2&type=$3&size=$1 [L]
```